# Google map icon- is it free to use?

Tags: icon, licensing, google

Can I use the google map icon on my website, if I link to google maps?

[image]

Comment: Did you check Google licensing agreements for Google Maps?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per Google after a little search:

> Things not permitted:
>
> Don't copy or imitate Google's trade dress, including the look and
>   feel of Google web design properties or Google brand packaging,
>   distinctive color combinations, typography, graphic designs, product
>   icons, or imagery associated with Google.

[Source](http://www.google.com/permissions/trademark/rules.html)

Comment: Also, specifically about the maps logo, http://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines.html says "Feel free to use a hyperlink on your website or within your application to send users to Google Maps — we appreciate it! Our one request is that you do not use the Google or Google Maps logos as the hyperlink. Please just use text or another image of your choice."

Comment: It seems this has changed since 2014; in particular, the bit quoted by @Glenn is no longer present on the page, which now instead (albeit only somewhat implicitly) states that you **are** allowed to use the logos to refer people to Google Maps. See also keiki’s new answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a lawyer. So I **can't** give you legal advise.

Please have a look here. For me it sounds you can use it, if it's clear that you are not google. So if it's a link to gmaps I interpret that you can use it.

https://about.google/brand-resource-center/products-and-services/geo-guidelines/#google-maps-google-earth-and-street-view

And especially
https://about.google/brand-resource-center/rules/